# hollow circle behind social icon

Tags: css, wordpress

Using CSS I would like to place a hollow circle behind a social icon and when I hover over the social icon the hollow circle is then filled, when I attempt to do this the circle is squished to the right of my social icon (fontawesome). I want the icon to be centered within the circle, also I would like to know the best way of going about this if I wanted to have have several social icons aligned horizontally each within a circle a distance of 100px apart. Thanks.

My CSS code:

```
.circle {
    border: 2px solid #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0px rgb( 255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0px rgb( 255, 255, 255);
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 86;

    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
}

.circle:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}

.fa-twitter {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Wordpress - Header.php

```
<div class='header-social-icons'>
                    <div class='twitter'>
                        <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>
                        <i class='circle'></i>          
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your social icon inside the circle div.

HTML:

```
        <div class='header-social-icons'>
         <div class='twitter circle'>
             <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>         
          </div>
      </div>
```

Updated CSS:

```
.fa-twitter {  display:block; }
.circle { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 15px;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/sUX2E/1/)

Comment: Works well, but the twitter icon still appears to be a little above the center is there a way to drop it down a bit? edit: never mind figured it out. used margin-top..

Answer (score 0):

Updated HTML:

```
<div class='header-social-icons'>
                    <div class='twitter'>
                        <i class='fa fa-twitter'></i>
                        <i class='circle'>Twitter</i>
                        <i class='circle'>Facebook</i>
                        <i class='circle'>Google+</i>
                        <i class='circle'>Reddit</i>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

---

Updated CSS:

```
   .circle {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 75px; 
    border: 20px solid #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0px rgb( 255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0px rgb( 255, 255, 255);
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 86;

    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

---

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/RUEbp/648/)
I hope this helped. Updated to align text's width and height.